# Accessing form attributes in custom form field type in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, modelform

I have a form that contains a foreignkey field (Place).  I've set up this field to use a custom form field type based off of CharField instead of ModelChoiceField as I want users to be able to use an autocomplete text input.  The autocomplete is working, and if the instance of the foreignkey'ed model exists, I have no issues.  However, if this instance of Place doesn't exist I want the user to be able to enter in the street address, town, state, and zip and use those to create a new Place using get_or_create in my custom field type.  My code is like so:

```
class PlaceAutoCompleteField(forms.CharField):
    def clean(self, value):
        super(PlaceAutoCompleteField, self).clean(value)
        place, created = Place.objects.get_or_create(name=value,
                            defaults={'street': self.form.cleaned_data['street'], 
                                      'town': self.form.cleaned_data['city'],
                                      'state': self.form.cleaned_data['state'],
                                      'zipcode': self.form.cleaned_data['zipcode']})
        return place

class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    place = PlaceAutoCompleteField()
    street = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = forms.CharField(max_length=40)
    state = USStateField()
    zipcode = USZipCodeField()

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = (.....)
```

I get the error: 'PlaceAutoCompleteField' object has no attribute 'form'

I'm not surprised by this, but I'm unsure how to pass the form data into my custom field.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of logic doesn't belong on the field - it belongs on the form, specifically in the form's `clean` method.

Comment: How can I do this in the form clean method?  Then I get the error: "Cannot assign "u'New Place'": "Event.place" must be a "Place" instance."